# Response Time is different for mulitiple execution of the application with the same request Performance problem

Tags: java, performance

My java application functionality is to provide reference data (basically loads lots of data from xml files into hashmap) and hence we request for one such data from the hashmap based on a id and we have such multiple has map for different set of business data. The problem is that when i tried executing the java application for the same request multiple times, the response times are different like 31ms, 48ms, 72ms, 120ms, 63ms etc. hence there is a considerable gap between the min and max time taken for the execution to complete. Ideally, i would expect the response times to be like, 63ms, 65ms, 61ms, 70ms, 61ms, but in my case the variation of the response time for the same request is varying hugely. I had used a opensource profile to understand if there is any extra execution of the methods or memory leak, but as per my understanding there was no problem. Please let me know what could be the reasons and how can i address this problem.

Answer (score 2):

There could be many causes:

- Is your Java application restarted for each run? If not, it could be that the garbage collector kicks in at an unfortunate time. If so, the JVM startup time could be responsible for the variations.
- Is anything else running on that machine?
- Is the disk cache "warmed up" in some cases, but not in others? That is, have the files been recently accessed so that they are still in memory?
- If this is a networked application, is there any network activity during the measurements?
- If there is a remote machine involved (e.g. a database server or a file server), do the above apply to that machine as well?

Use a profiler to find out which piece of code is responsible for the variations in time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't run a real-time system, then you can't be sure it will execute within a certain time.

OSes constantly do other things, mostly housekeeping tasks, and providing the system other services. This easily will slow down the rest of your system for 50ms.

There also might be time that you need to wait for IO. Such as harddisks or network communication.

Besides that there is also the fact that your JVM doesn't do any real-time promises. This can mean the garbage collector runs through. The effect of this is very small on a normal application, but can be large if you create and forget lots of objects (as you might do when loading many or large files).

Finally it can be your algorithm (do you run the same data each time?) if you have different data, you can have different execution times.